# Django - One to Many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, relational-database, one-to-many

I have user and user role models. There are 3 user roles as teacher, student, admin. One user should have only one role but if I make one-to-one relationship only one user can be attached to one role. I want there can be many students, many teacher, many admins but one user must only have one role. I couldn't figure out how to design this relationship.

I have 2 models as User and User_Role.

```
class role(models.Model):
   role_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class user(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a `ForeignKey` from the `User` model to the `Role`, so:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`user`</s> to `User`.

Comment: but in that way we can use multiple select to role for user right? By the way thanks for the information.

Comment: @nogabemist: no a `ForeignKey` selects one `Role` per user: this is also implemented as a single column that will contain the primary key of the `Role` it refers to. A `ManyToManyField` allows to select multiple (for the same user). A `ForeignKey` is a many-to-one relation, so many users can select (possibly the same) single `Role`.